# PHP database connection - error when selecting database

Tags: php, connection, database-connection

I'm having problems when trying to connect to a database with PHP. I am getting the following errors

```
Notice: Undefined variable: dbhandle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/connection/Connection.php on line 17

Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/connection/Connection.php on line 17
Could not select test
```

My connection file:

```
<?php

  function Connection() {
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $hostname = "localhost"; 

  $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
  echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

  mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
  }

  function SelectDatabase() {
  $name = "test";
  $selected = mysql_select_db("$name",$dbhandle) 
    or die("Could not select $name");
}
    ?>
```

Index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<?php include 'Connection.php'; ?>

</head>
<body>
<?php Connection() ?>
<?php SelectDatabase() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you still using an outdate API and why do you mix database code with HTML code?

Comment: What would be the most current API?

Comment: @Colin747 - PDO or mysqli. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: `"$var"` is a sign of cargo-cult programming.

Answer (score 2):

`$dbhandle` is out of scope when used in `SelectDatabase`. You might want to have `Connection()` return `$dbhandle`. That way, you could do:

```
<?php SelectDatabase(Connection()) ?>
```

Of course, you would have to modify `SelectDatabase` to take the connection variable as a parameter.

Or, alternatively, you could make `$dbhandle` a global variable so you can use it anywhere in your script.

Answer (score 2):

It's a scoping problem: `$dbhandle` is local to `Connection()`

You can either use a global variable (put `global $dbhandle;` at the start of both functions), which is not very elegant, or

```
function Connection() {
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $hostname = "localhost"; 

  $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
  echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

  mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

  return $dbhandle;
}

function SelectDatabase($dbhandle) {
  $name = "test";
  $selected = mysql_select_db("$name",$dbhandle) 
    or die("Could not select $name");
}
```

and

```
</head>
<body>
<?php $db=Connection() ?>
<?php SelectDatabase($db) ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is easy to spot; you never pass the `$dbhandle` parameter to your function.  You need to do this so the function can use the parameter; due to scope issues, not all parameters are immediately available to all functions.

Try the following instead:

```
function SelectDatabase($dbhandle) {
    $name = "test";
     $selected = mysql_select_db("$name",$dbhandle) 
         or die("Could not select $name");
}
```

And then, when you call the function:

```
SelectDatabase($dbhandle);
```

Make sure that $dbhandle is global.

Either that, or as others have pointed out, have `Connection()` return the variable name, and use it within the call.

Secondly, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.  I would suggest you use [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

you don't make your life easier :p

you just have to do this :

```
$connexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test","root","password");
```

and if you want to make sql request just :

```
$connexion->query("SQL REQUEST ....");
```